# How to see Digital Signatures in PDF files using objective C

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview, digital-signature

I have a PDF viewer in my app. I am simply loading the PDF file into a UIWebView. But when the PDF contains digital signature, it is not displayed in WebView. All other content of the PDF is displayed. Only signature area is left blank. I checked with the Preview, and Safari in OSX  also, and the result is the same.

Then I downloaded the Adobe Reader app for Mac, and tried to open the PDF. It displayed the signature correctly!!

Can anybody tell me whether there is any mechanism in objective C, to display the signature of PDF files.

Comment: I believe adobe made the metadata part of a PDF public.  I'm not quite sure if signatures count as metadata (especially because the PDF spec is 1000+ pages long), but it's worth a shot to get it through the Core Graphics PDF API.

Comment: Digital Signatures aren't really part of the metadata. A digital signature is stored in a signature field. You can find it in the /Contents entry of the value (/V) of the field dictionary. For more info, read http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures

Comment: A good read also would be the relevant part of the PDF spec [ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), especially section 12.7.4.5 on *Signature Fields* and section 12.8 on *Digital Signatures*. And, of course, the XFA spec if the signatures in question actually are XML signatures.

Comment: Thank you all. It seems that there is no built-in way to achieve this, other than parsing the PDF using Quartz 2D or simple binary parser.  I will try to implement this as soon as possible, and update you soon!

Comment: This is very unfortunate, even after 4 years they havent include this feature in UIWebView?

Answer (score 1):

Adobe documents how to use Digital Signatures in PDF files. See section 12.8, page 466 of the [Adobe PDF 1.7 spec](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

However, as you've discovered, many viewers of pdf files, including the pdf viewer built into Google Chrome ignore Digital Signatures. This is rather unfortunate as Digital Signatures become more popular.

If you haven't done so yet, file a bug report against the UIWebView. Or a feature enhancement request. It is non-trivial to add full Digital Signature support, but it's a great feature.

**Adding Digital Signature Support**

As a first step of support, you could consider just showing the information about the document's Digital Signatures and verifying them. -- it is important not just to show Digital Signatures, you also need to [verify](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8034/how-digital-signature-verification-process-works) them.

Most important part of verification, imho, is to verify that the document was not changed since it was signed. Verifying that you trust the root cert of the signer's cert is good to do but, in practice, is not as important as doc integrity. On the other hand, it all depends on your app and its environment.

As a second step, you could show the graphical signature that is often included with the Digital Signature(s) at the right spot on the document's page(s).

It is common for a pdf to include multiple Digital Signatures. It is also common for a pdf to included multiple "electronic signatures" along with a verifying Digital Signature.

An "Electronic Signature" is merely a graphical signature shown on a page of the pdf. It does not involve any cryptographic functions, does not assure document integrity, nor signer non-repudiation (no signer certs are involved).

Because Digital Signatures take real time to verify, pdfs sometimes include multiple electronic signatures, eg as initials on each page. And then a single Digital Signature to cover the entire document.